# New VPC not showing in selection list for new DocumentDB Cluster

Tags: amazon-vpc, aws-documentdb

I created a new VPC for our pre-production environment and am attempting to create a DocumentDB cluster within it.

Per the VPC Prerequisites at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/db-cluster-create.html all I need is to ensure there are at least 3 subnets across 3 different availability zones in the new VPC to do so.

When I try to create it though, my new VPC is not an available selection. What am I missing?

As we can see from the below screenshots the VPC has a private subnet in 1a 1b and 1d, yet it's not selectable for my new DB Cluster

Thanks in advance!

[image: subnet listing]

[image: vpc dropdown]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to create a subnet group (from the DocumentDB page) with my subnets in there and then everything worked out great